# JMeter Internal server Error, Response Code : 500 on posting a form

Tags: jmeter

[image]JMeter Internal server Error, Response Code : 500 on posting a form.
I am trying to load test our banking application with JMeter.I have successfully logged in to the application. Now I am trying to create an accuont. Account opening form has five pages and I am getting internal server error when I post the first page of the account opening process.
I have provided all possible values which are required for posting first page (As required in the browser to make it go to next page).
I have added the Cookie manager and Header manager also.
But this fails in JMeter.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: As it's an internal server error, the easiest way to get to the root cause would be to check the server's logs.

Comment: Yeah we need more information on the error. I'ld try to record the requests with Chromes dev tool to a HAR file, [then convert it to a JMX](https://flood.io/blog/16-convert-har-files-to-jmeter-test-plans), this way you could avoid "human error", maybe you missed something. Also try different HTTP implementations (there is 3)

Comment: Ok... you need to tell us what do you do for these values in the request? Is it hard-coded? 
      view:content:innerform:chanel                
 view:content:innerform:cycleGroupContainer......             
 x

Comment: Thanks guys, for all help.I simulated the account opening form in Chrome and used Developer tools to track all requests to server and it worked.
Thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add "`Http Header Manager`" user your "`Http Request`" which is failing. 
Click on add button to add on column under "`Headers stored  in the Header Manager`"

- Add Name : Content-Type
- Add value : application/json
- save it and run it.

This may solve your 500 (internal server error) error problem.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to try recording to ensure you’re not missing:

- header
- cookie
- parameter

or any additional http request.

Read:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html